# How IBM Filenet Integrated with Angular application

Tags: javascript, angularjs, filenet-content-engine, filenet-cpe

I'm not familiar with Filenet.

I am using IBM FileNet as document management system. How Can I consume Filenet web services Apis in my AngularJs Application.

Please Help me out, if anyone has tried this.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Use the FileNet api to develop a class or web service that returns the records from FileNet and then have the Angular app digest the records returned.

See:

http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/data/library/techarticle/dm-0810carpenter/

and

https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSNW2F_5.2.1/com.ibm.p8.ce.dev.ce.doc/gs_concepts.htm

Answer (score 1):

In very simple terms, FileNet is a just another content Management system.

- It has an API that you use to query the backend(Content Engine) for a
  documents that matches your criteria.
- Each document you get has content(most of the time, a physical file), and properties (In fileNet terms MetaData).
- You will need some technology in the middle to translate the data you aquired to a form that is consumable by Angular (JSON). Something that we can call for the moment a Rest Engine.
- This "Engine" should help you expose end points (Simple web addresses http:///Path/To/Data) that is attached to java methods that returns the JSONs you made.

  To be able to pull that out successfully, you need to have a good grasp of Angular (Services), and then knowledge of one "Rest Engine" (or something you can use similarly, even a servlet would help you for the moment), and finally a very simple knowledge of FileNet basic operations.

Answer (score -1):

A RESTFUL service tier that leverages FileNet EJB API which are much faster than WS APIs (esp. when in a distributed deployed environment) is to be built for this if you are working in an enterprise-level project.